# How do I unit test when ActiveRecord has been turned off?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I have turned ActiveRecord off in my Rails app in the environment config:

```
Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
  config.frameworks -= [:active_record]
end
```

I have models that do not extend ActiveRecord::Base and I want to unit test these models. When I run the tests I get the `uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Base` error.

How can I test my models when I don't have active record on?

Comment: Did use script/generate to create the models?  Is there something left over in the default tests that is looking for AR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could cheat.  Add the following to your tests:

```
class ActiveRecord
    class Base
        end
    end
```

But first I'd recommend tracking down what is referring to ActiveRecord::Base.  You think you aren't using it, but you may be wrong.

Comment: Embarrassing. I totally had an temporary ActiveRecord model that I had not deleted. Thanks!